# Pelo menos uma das expressões resultantes em uma especificação CASE deve ser uma expressão diferente da constante NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO FILAS_CARTOES (COD_ASSOCIADO, SEQUENCIA_ADICIONAL, COD_USUARIO, DATA_REGISTRO, PROVISORIO, GERAR_SMS, STATUS, PRIORIDADE)
                VALUES (
                    @COD_ASSOCIADO
                    , CASE @SEQUENCIA_ADICIONAL WHEN 0 THEN NULL END
                    , @COD_USUARIO
                    , GETDATE()
                    , 'N'
                    , 'N'
                    , 'P'
                    , 1
                );
```

erro:
Pelo menos uma das expressões resultantes em uma especificação CASE deve ser uma expressão diferente da constante NULL.

Esse é o erro, o que precisa ser feito, alguem pde me ajudar?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Altere seu `CASE` para `CASE @SEQUENCIA_ADICIONAL WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE @SEQUENCIA_ADICIONAL  END`